# is it possible to embed HTML in flash?

Tags: html, flash, web, embed

I have a media rich website built exclusively on flash.
I want to be able to embed some HTML/Javascript in it, sort of like an iframe or a browser window.
is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057294/is-there-a-webbrowser-that-can-run-inside-flash-player

Comment: @Papasmile yes, put that as an answer please

Comment: Please see Is there a webbrowser that can run inside Flash player? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057294/is-there-a-webbrowser-that-can-run-inside-flash-player